# How to pass --dev flag to sadf in sar files

Tags: bash, performance-testing, sar

I have my sar file in `/var/log/sysstat/sa02`. I have a block device called `nvme0n1`. I want to use `sadf command` and filter only `nvme0n1` as results.

I used the following command.
`sadf -U /var/log/sysstat/sa02 -d  --dev=nvme0n1 -- -d -p`

But as a result, the usage of sadf comes like

```
Usage: sadf [ options ] [ <interval> [ <count> ] ] [ <datafile> | -[0-9]+ ]
Options are:
[ -C ] [ -c | -d | -g | -j | -p | -r | -x ] [ -H ] [ -h ] [ -T | -t | -U ] [ -V ]
[ -O <opts> [,...] ] [ -P { <cpu> [,...] | ALL } ]
[ -s [ <hh:mm[:ss]> ] ] [ -e [ <hh:mm[:ss]> ] ]
[ -- <sar_options> ]
```

In the same manner, I want to pass `--iface` flag also, still I get the same result. I used the iface flag as follows.

`sadf -U -d /var/log/sysstat/sa02 --iface=ens5 -- -n DEV`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need new version sysstat

```
sadf --help
Usage: sadf [ options ] [ <interval> [ <count> ] ] [ <datafile> | -[0-9]+ ]
Options are:
[ -C ] [ -c | -d | -g | -j | -l | -p | -r | -x ] [ -H ] [ -h ] [ -T | -t | -U ] [ -V ]
[ -O <opts> [,...] ] [ -P { <cpu> [,...] | ALL } ]
[ --dev=<dev_list> ] [ --fs=<fs_list> ] [ --iface=<iface_list> ]
[ -s [ <hh:mm[:ss]> ] ] [ -e [ <hh:mm[:ss]> ] ]
[ -- <sar_options> ]
```